# php curl array handling

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

First of all **Hello** I am currenttly scraping from a website the current price value of EURO & Dollars of my country to use them later for counting the total price value of the product the company bought.,

```
[prix] => 
Array ( 
[0] => 212,00 DA    //Sell price
[1] => 213.00 DA    // Buy price
[2] => 184,00 DA    //Sell price
[3] => 185,00 DA  ) //Buy price
[nom] => 
Array ( 
[0] => Euro (€)  name of [0 and 1] prix array
[1] => Dollar US ($)) name of [ 2 and 3] prix array
```

My Actual problem is that i want to parse the information of both array in once 
in a table (as shown below) :

CURRENCY NAME | SELL  | Buy  |

EURO | 212,00 DA | 213,00 DA

DOLLAR | 184,00 DA | 185,00 DA

```
<?php
    $url='http://myurl/';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    ;
    $pro=array();
    preg_match_all("/<td>[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*.[0-9]+ DA<\/td>/",$html,$match);
        $pro['prix']=$match['0'];

         preg_match_all('!<td><a href=".*">\K(.+?(?=<\/a><\/td>))!',$html,$match);
        $pro['nom']=$match['0'];

        curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Hello! Can you show a representative example of the actual HTML content? Also, can you explain what your current code is doing that's different from what you want? Is that PHP code producing the output example in the first code block?

Comment: Hello , Actually the problem i am facing is that i couldn't cut the array into 2 part's one for the selling price and one for the buying price  and i can't combine both array since the number of rows are not the same
I am scraping from a website the current price value of EURO & Dollars of my country to use them later for counting the total price value of the product the company bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the values into chunks and combine those with the keys.

```
$currencies = array_combine($pro['nom'], array_chunk($pro['prix'], 2));
```

Then iterate the result of that to build your table.

```
foreach ($currencies as $currency => list($sell, $buy)) {
    var_dump($currency, $sell, $buy);
    // add whatever HTML you want
}
```